# Two arms but no hands. What am I?

Tags: riddle

I have a neck but no hands,
Two arms but no hands.
I go with you to school;
And I go with you to work.

Comment: @IAmInPLS  Is there any reason why was it necessary to change the title of a two-month question, possibly throwing away information? I strongly suggest a rollback.

Comment: @Matsmath http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5156/should-we-edit-who-what-am-i-questions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems too obvious but are you...

> A shirt? Has a neck and arms but no hands and is commonly worn to work and school...

Or similarly,

> A jumper/sweater?

Comment: I wasn't expecting anyone to get it this fast, good job! I'll have to accept it tommorow but still.

Comment: So this rules out sweater vests and dickies.  Thats racist.

Answer (score 6):

You are

> BAG

neck but no hands

> bag looks like neck

Two arms but no hands

> arms are where we put our hands to hold it.

School and work

> Bag taken to school and work

Comment: This was my other thought. Thought the "neck" part was a bit of a stretch though.

Comment: ^^ Creative though!

Comment: bag has a neck, its that little coat hanger apparatus